# How to find the min/max value of a common key in a list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max, min

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```py
[{'price': 99, 'barcode': '2342355'}, {'price': 88, 'barcode': '2345566'}]
```

I want to find the `min()` and `max()` prices. Now, I can sort this easily enough using a key with a lambda expression (as found in another Stack Overflow post), so if there is no other way I'm not stuck. However, from what I've seen there is almost always a direct way in Python, so this is an opportunity for me to learn a bit more.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

```
lst = [{'price': 99, 'barcode': '2342355'}, {'price': 88, 'barcode': '2345566'}]

maxPricedItem = max(lst, key=lambda x:x['price'])
minPricedItem = min(lst, key=lambda x:x['price'])
```

This tells you not just what the max price is but also which item is most expensive.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice touch, returning the entire item.  Not needed in this instance, but very definitely a keeper for the future.

Comment: How would you do this to find the largest 5 items in a list?  (not just the max)

Comment: @thomas.mac You could sort and then select the top 5? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell This is magical! Can you help me find the resources to explain this? Thanks!

Comment: This works perfectly. Following @thomas.mac's comment , is there an easy way to get *all* the minima if there are several (as a list of matching dict, for instance) ?

Comment: How would you make sure that ['price'] exists in the dict?

Answer (score 75):

There are several options.  Here is a straight-forward one:

```
seq = [x['the_key'] for x in dict_list]
min(seq)
max(seq)
```

[Edit]

If you only wanted to iterate through the list once, you could try this (assuming the values could be represented as `int`s):

```
import sys

lo,hi = sys.maxint,-sys.maxint-1
for x in (item['the_key'] for item in dict_list):
    lo,hi = min(x,lo),max(x,hi)
```

Comment: I accept this as the answer as it not only gives the answer, but it also showed me that one can abstract sequences.  Darn, Python is a beautiful language.  Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need the `seq`, and the list is large, this can be inefficient since the memory for the entire list has to be allocated just to find the max.

Comment: It throws `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'maxint'`

Comment: @Suncatcher in Python 3, `sys.maxint` has changed to `sys.maxsize`

Answer (score 55):

I think the most direct (and most Pythonic) expression would be something like:

```
min_price = min(item['price'] for item in items)
```

This avoids the overhead of sorting the list -- and, by using a generator expression, instead of a list comprehension -- actually avoids creating any lists, as well. Efficient, direct, readable... Pythonic!

Answer (score 15):

One answer would be mapping your dicts to the value of interest inside a generator expression, and then applying the built-ins `min` and `max`.

```
myMax = max(d['price'] for d in myList)
myMin = min(d['price'] for d in myList)
```

Comment: nitpick: those are generator expressions. List comprehensions are surrounded by `[` and `]`, and actually generate a Python list as an intermediate step.

Comment: @dcrosta, yes, thank you, you're right of course.  I changed the wording since that was embarrassing.

Answer (score 5):

can also use this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [{'price': 99, 'barcode': '2342355'}, {'price': 88, 'barcode': '2345566'}]  
max(map(itemgetter('price'), lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

**And to add to this great page: the top answer in a generic convenient function:**

```py
def takeMaxFromDictList(listOfDicts: list, keyToLookAt: str) -> dict:
  return max( listOfDicts, key=lambda x: x[keyToLookAt] )

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

examplelist = [{'score': 0.995, 'label': 'buildings'},
               {'score': 0.002, 'label': 'mountain'},
               {'score': 0.001, 'label': 'forest'}]
 
print ( takeMaxFromDictList(examplelist, 'score') )
```

`>>> {'score': 0.995, 'label': 'buildings'}`