# How to get object minimum/maximum value of specific key in python?

Tags: python, object, minimum

I have a list like this:

```
list = [
    {'price': 2, 'amount': 34},
    {'price': 7, 'amount': 123},
    {'price': 5, 'amount': 495}
]
```

How to get object with minimum/maximum value of specific key in python?
With this I can get the minimum value:

```
min(obj['price']  for obj in list) # 2
```

but what I want to get is a whole object

> {'price': 2, 'amount':34}

How can I achieve this? Is there a simple way without foreach etc?

Comment: Be careful to not name your objects with builtin function names e.g. `list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In List of Dicts, find min() value of a common Dict field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320871/in-list-of-dicts-find-min-value-of-a-common-dict-field)

Comment: (Although most of the answers in the linked question only return the price so perhaps it isn't a great duplicate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `key` for your `min` function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

min(my_list, key=itemgetter('price'))
```

Also don't use python's built-in key-words and/or data structure names as your variables and objects name. It will confuse the interpreter by shadowing the built-in names.

Answer (score 8):

To add on Kasramvd answer, you can also do this with lambda.

```
>>> foo = [
...     {'price': 2, 'amount': 34},
...     {'price': 7, 'amount': 123},
...     {'price': 5, 'amount': 495}
... ]
>>> max(foo, key=lambda x: x['price'])
{'amount': 123, 'price': 7}
>>> min(foo, key=lambda x: x['price'])
{'amount': 34, 'price': 2}
>>>
```

Comment: Just of the sake of completion, I'd like to add that the `itemgetter` approach in the accepted answer is faster that the approach outlined here, i.e, using `lambda`.