# How can i get min value in array from JSONField

Tags: json, django, postgresql, orm

i have a model and this model have a JSONField

```
class Book(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

And this field have an array.

```
data = {
     'outlet':[
     {'price': 100},
     {'price': 200},
     {'price': 300}
     ]}
```

I want to get min value of outlet price.I've tried use KeyTextTransform and Min func. I can do easily if outlet not an array. But unfortunately i have to work on array in this case.

I want to solve this problem with ORM. If this is impossible, i'll solve this problem with pythonic As a last resort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In List of Dicts, find min() value of a common Dict field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320871/in-list-of-dicts-find-min-value-of-a-common-dict-field)

Answer (score -1):

try this: 
you can first map the list of dicts to a list of prices (integers)

`map(lambda outlet: outlet['price'], data['outlet'])`

than you can simply use the **min** function to extract the minim price possible.

`min(map(lambda outlet: outlet['price'], data['outlet']))`